# Allow user to change the colors of the Website

Tags: php, sass, frontend

How to implement to allow user to change the colors of the website via selecting the colors on the browser.

For example on the browser:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s33Dz.png)

When user press Save then it will need to update the CSS but what is good approach doing this? The CSS is originally compiled via SASS or SCSS.

I could save CSS content to the database. All the colors related will have like a tag (eg: `background-color: [bg_color]`) in the css and PHP will replace it. But there must be a better alternative way?

I have notice there is `scssphp` - If I were to use `scssphp` tool, how would do I that in my case to update the colors from user selection? The colors varibles are stored in `_colors.scss` file.

Comment: Have you even searched this on Google first?!!!

Comment: This question is very broad.